# Ajax in asp net core 5 Bad request 400

Tags: javascript, c#, json, ajax, asp.net-core

I got error like "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()" when i'm trying to run function ajax in javascript. What to do? Please, help me!

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}
<div class="container">
<p id="scanned"></p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function Q(el) {
            if (typeof el === "string") {
                var els = document.querySelectorAll(el);
                return typeof els === "undefined" ? undefined : els.length > 1 ? els : els[0];
            }
            return el;
        }
        var txt = "innerText" in HTMLElement.prototype ? "innerText" : "textContent";
        var scannedQR = Q("#scanned");
      var args = {
            autoBrightnessValue: 100,
            resultFunction: function (res) {
                [].forEach.call(scannerLaser, function (el) {
                    fadeOut(el, 0.5);
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        fadeIn(el, 0.5);
                    }, 300);
                });
                scannedImg.src = res.imgData;
                scannedQR[txt] = res.code;
                UserCheckId();
            }
          };
          function UserCheckId() {
              $.ajax({
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    crossDomain: true,
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: '@Url.Action("UserCheckId", "Home")',
                    data: { qrcode: JSON.stringify(scannedQR[txt]) },
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });
            }
</script>
```

```
        [HttpPost]
        [AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]
        public ActionResult UserCheckId(string qrcode)
        {
            string result = qrcode;
            return Json(result, System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

i updated the code and showed where i am calling function "UserCheckId".

Comment: Is the first example code places in a a JS file or in a Razor page?

Comment: i write scripts in razor pages

Comment: @Peter remove controller from URL **HomeController** to **Home**

Comment: @Arib Yousuf same error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()"

Comment: 400 Bad Request-  ```data:{ qrcode : JSON.stringify(scannedQR[txt]) }```

Comment: @MD.RAKIBHASAN didn't help(

Comment: i'm used this code on asp net framework and he worked! But, he doesn't work on asp net core 5, i don't undestand what to do(...

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution.
I added below line in Startup.cs in Configure and it worked.

```
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
```